# How to play video in full screen, without html5

Tags: video, embed, fullscreen

We have to support IE 8 so the HTML5 video tag is not an option. The application has to support Quick Time player, so the Flash plug in can not be used.

I am using `object` and `embed` tags to embed video in HTML. It doesn't show a full screen option. How do I add a control which, when clicked, opens a new page and plays video in full screen.

Comment: Here is the code that worked.<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
CODEBASE="https://appldnld.apple.com.edgesuite.net/content.info.apple.com/QuickTime/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" 
WIDTH="480" HEIGHT="297" >
<PARAM NAME="src" VALUE="URL">
<PARAM NAME="autoplay" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME="scale" VALUE="ToFit">
<PARAM NAME="controller" value="true">
<video SRC="URL" TYPE="image/x-macpaint"
PLUGINSPAGE="https://www.apple.com/quicktime/download" QTSRC="URL" 
WIDTH="480" HEIGHT="297" SCALE="ToFit" controls="true">
</video>
</OBJECT>

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that worked.

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" CODEBASE="appldnld.apple.com.edgesuite.net/content.info.apple.com/…; WIDTH="480" HEIGHT="297" >
  <PARAM NAME="src" VALUE="URL">
  <PARAM NAME="autoplay" VALUE="false">
  <PARAM NAME="scale" VALUE="ToFit">
  <PARAM NAME="controller" value="true">

  <video SRC="URL" TYPE="image/x-macpaint" PLUGINSPAGE="apple.com/quicktime/download"; QTSRC="URL" WIDTH="480" HEIGHT="297" SCALE="ToFit" controls="true"></video>
</OBJECT>
```